# Calling `delete` on an object owned by a `unique_ptr` using another pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, unique-ptr, delete-operator

I have a pointer to class initialized by the `new` operator. Then I use this pointer to setup a `std::unique_ptr`. Now, as far as my understanding goes, the following code has double delete, once the manually called `delete` operator and then when the unique pointer goes out of scope. How does this code run "correctly", i.e., without a runtime exception?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
        std::cout<<"In A::A()\n";
    }
    ~A()
    {
        std::cout<<"In A::~A()\n";
    }
    void printMyStr()
    {
        std::cout<<"In A::printMyStr()\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout<<"hello world!\n";
    A * pa = new A();
    std::unique_ptr<A> upa(pa);
    pa->printMyStr();
    upa->printMyStr();
    delete pa;  // How does this not create problems?
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
hello world!
In A::A()
In A::printMyStr()
In A::printMyStr()
In A::~A()
In A::~A()
```

Clearly the destructor runs twice, even if there is only one object that is created. How is this possible?

Note: I am using gcc 7.3.0 on 64-bit linux.

Comment: It's just undefined behaviour, not something that will throw an exception. If you run it through valgrind it should tell you there's a problem.

Comment: "How is this possible?" With undefined behavior **anything** is possible. (Including "appearing to work normally".)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Double delete is undefined behaviour.

Undefined behaviour doesn't guarantee a runtime exception; that would be defined.  Undefined behaviour means anything can happen.  This can include time travel, formatting harddrives, emailing browser history to your contacts, or nothing at all.

I have yet to experience browser history being emailed, that I know of.  I have experienced the rest.

Comment: Have you really experienced the formatting of hard-drives?

Comment: @einpoklum I have experienced filesystem corruption as a result of UB, though not reformatting. But there is no reason why it could not happen.  "Time travel" on the other hand....

Comment: @einpok it was memory corruption, passing wrong (garbage) argument to a (rather scary) filesystem API, clearing the format of a HDD, if I remember right.  But yes, it was a bug (with UB) whose symptom was "HDD loses format".

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont: But that's kind of cheating. I mean, a filesystem API's _defined_ behavior can involve deleting things. There's this CppCon 2017 talk, [Undefined behavior is awesome](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ehyHyAIa5so) where Piotr Padlewski explains how to maybe make that happen really inadvertantly and unexpectedly.

Comment: @einp I don't recall exactly what the API was.  It might have been an attempt to "create temp file" or something.  Destroying a drive was not one of the things that function was supposed to be able to do.  And I believe it was DOS days, where user space had full access to drive hardware.

Answer (score 0):

If at some point prior to the unique_ptr instance going out of scope you decide you want to delete the managed object, just do `unique_ptr_instance.reset(nullptr)`. This calls the deleter and causes the managed object to become nullptr, deleting which when the instance finally goes out of scope is a no-op.